# rich text editor...add class on the fly

Tags: javascript, image, class, rte

I'm using the next code block to insert an image on a editable div. I want to know if it's possible to add a class on the fly to the image...

```
function insertImg() {  
var src = prompt('Please specify the link of the image.');
if(src)
{
document.execCommand('insertImage', false, src); 
}}
```

something like this:

```
<img src="xxxxx.gif" class="myClass">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var style = document.createElement('style');

style.type = 'text/css';

style.innerHTML = '.myClass { }';

document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(style);

document.getElementsByTagNames('img').className = 'myClass'; // or use getByID.....
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but more specifically, I have 2 html buttons: 1- 'insert image class A' and 2- 'insert image class B'... I'm calling the insertImg function on the click event...